# React native flatlist blank area, could not load all items problem

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flatlist

I'm facing a very annoying problem with FlatList in react native. We have been implementing chat feature in our app. The problems are blank area appears and FlatList data updated but the item could not be rendered.

The problems occurred when the list of messages increasing. In the view which contains the FlatList, there are many components that made the performance goes down. I think this mights be one of the reasons that lead to the problem.

Our code is quite heavy so I wrapped a smaller project to this repo https://github.com/luatvudinh/chatProject.

Please give me a hand. This took me 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding android:largeHeap="true" to AndroidManifest.xml Application section.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).